# FOSUserBundle template override not working with Symfony Flex

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with Symfony Flex and FOSUserBundle. I can't override default FOSUserBundle templates. I tried to do everything following the Symfony documentation, tutorials and nothing works. It's just like Twig won't take my **layout.html.twig** to render instead of default FOSUserBundle.

Templates dir tree looks like it should following new Symfony Flex structure:

```
- templates
   - default
   - FOSUserBundle
      - views
         - layout.html.twig
   - base.html.twig
```

Maybe anyone has encountered similar problem with Symfony Flex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pull request that was merged in Symfony 3.4 at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/24179 and available since `3.4-BETA1` and `4.0-BETA1` specifies that you need to place the template at `templates/bundles/FOSUserBundle/layout.html.twig`. PR description mentions exactly this usecase as its example.

In Symfony 3.3, it should work by placing the template in `src/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig`

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try it out today. I didn't come across this PR sadly. I've seen other PR's but they weren't about templating. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: It works when placed in `src\Resources`! Thanks a lot! Now I need to prepare myself for deeper looking into the PR's and deeper searching when something won't work.

Answer (score 2):

- templates

  - default
  - FOSUserBundle

    - layout.html.twig

it works for me

Comment: Note that the `view` folder is not required to override the `bundle/src/Resources/views/layout.html.twig` in Symfony4 as mentioned in another post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't anderstand why that doesn't work for me with symfony 4.0.8 in:
- templates
 - FOSUserBundle
      - layout.html.twig

but it works in
src
  - Resources
    - FOSUserBundle
      - views
        - layout.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with symfony4 and fosUserBundle per to https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/overriding.html,
for registration_content overriding i put my template file in templates\bundles\FOSUserBundle\Registration\register_content.html.twig 
and it ready to works
hope work for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to drop my answer here, because I am in a constant uphill battle with this bundle.

I copied the desired templates from the bundle in vendor and at first put them in,

`project_root/src/Resources/FOSUserBundle`

However after reading the documentation, it seems that it should be placed in `project_root/templates/bundles/name_of_bundle/*`.

However that didn't work because FOSUserBundle file structure is not adhering to symfonys conventions, you have to move things out of the `views` folder.

So rather than `project_root/templates/bundles/name_of_bundle/views`, move everything out of the `views` folder and into the parent name_of_bundle folder.

Comment: For anyone else struggling with sym4> and flex, the way to reference the FOSUserBundle templates from within one another is no longer {% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %} but rather {% extends "bundles/FOSUserBundle/layout.html.twig" %} (provided you placed your overriding templates in templates/bundles/FOSUserBundle/)

Answer (score -1):

In your custom User bundle you must decalre the parent bundle

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class YourNameSpaceUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

> Note: Symfony Flex is alpha software; use it at your own risk

Comment: Note that bundle inheritance is deprecated since Symfony 3.4.

Comment: There are couple of links. RFC: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/24048, PR: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/24160, blog post: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-deprecated-bundle-inheritance

Answer (score -3):

```
- templates
 - FOSUserBundle
      - layout.html.twig
```

Work for me too in Symfony 4.0.8 !